# ' DEBUG ' is not recognized as internal command with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, velocity

the following command doesn't work when i execute it in the console :

```
 DEBUG=1 JASMINE_DEBUG=1 VELOCITY_DEBUG=1 VELOCITY_DEBUG_MIRROR=1 meteor
```

I got the following message :

```
' DEBUG ' is not recognized as internal command
```

Comment: What OS and shell are you running?

Comment: i am using Windows 10 as OS  and cmd shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using Windows? Instead of adding these environment variables on the command line at run time, use the following commands to set these variables:

```
set DEBUG=1
set JASMINE_DEBUG=1
set VELOCITY_DEBUG=1
set VELOCITY_DEBUG_MIRROR=1
```

Then run meteor. To turn it off you will need to set them back to zero or clear them. You can write a bat script to do this for you to make it easier.